# Select varchar data become int or float

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select varchar data like '2+2+3' with result '7'.

I have one column to store data calculation like above sample but need to select the result of the calculation only.

I tried `Select Convert(int,'2+2+3') as result` but it didn't work.

Please help if you know how to solve it.
Thanks

Comment: Where do these values come from and why are they stored like that? If they are user supplied and you plan to use dynamic SQL to evaluate them you've basically built a SQL injection factory

Comment: Hello, actually data store on the table is calculation for selling price. For example, "USD Rate + Production Cost + Add Cost". The parameter on the calculation will be different for each country and I need to replace them with value like sample above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To evaluate an equation you need to use dynamic SQL i.e. build a select statement including the equation and then execute it e.g.

```
declare @Equation varchar(128) = '2+2+3';
declare @Sql nvarchar(max) = 'select ' + @Equation + ' as result';
exec sp_executesql @Sql;
```

Returns:

| result |
| --- |
| 7 |

Note: As pointed out in the comments, this is very dangerous should the equation SQL ever contain a SQL injection.

As suggested by Martin Smith a possible safeguard would be:

```
declare @Equation varchar(128) = '2+2+3';

-- Only allow numbers and operators
if @Equation like '%[^0-9 .+/*-]%' return; -- or throw.

...
```

Comment: [Did you really name your equation `1; DROP TABLE Students;--`?](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @MartinSmith would blocking the SQL if it had a semi-colon be safe? Or are there ways around that as well?

Comment: Probably safest just to allow list numeric characters and arithmetic operators `IF @Equation LIKE '%[^0-9 .+/*-]%' THROW ...`. As SQL Server doesn't require `;` as statement delimiter in most cases

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I got your logic and do modification on my query and it works!

Answer (score 2):

As you know by now, SQL Server does not support macro substitution, nor does it have an `Eval()` function.   That said, this leaves Dynamic SQL.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table (id int,Expression varchar(150))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'1+2')
,(2,'(1+2)*3')
,(3,'datediff(DAY,''2018-01-01'',getdate())')  -- Added Just for Fun


Declare @SQL varchar(max) = (Select string_agg(concat('(',ID,',',Expression,')'),',') From @YourTable  )
Exec('Select * from (values ' + @SQL + ')A([ID],[Value])')
```

**Results**

```
ID  Value
1   3
2   9
3   1833
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your contribution. I get new knowledge from this.

Answer (score 0):

data

```
declare @a table( vals varchar(max))
insert into @a
(vals) values
('2+3'),
('2+3+4'),
('2+3+4+5'),
('2+3+4+5+7');
```

use `string_split`,`subquery` and cast as follows

```
select
-- ID,
Sum(Cast(a.value as float)) as result
from   (select row_number()
                 over (
                   order by (select null)) ID,
               vals
        from   @a) b
       CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(vals, '+') a
group  by ID
order  by ID
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/t8w3O9Ez)

Answer (score -1):

It is better to do such operations (arithmetic and converting) in the programming language part.
'2+2+3' this part needs a parsing, you can provide it via programming language or you need to write a function and then call it with eval. This is too risky. And it's bad programming, do the parsing on the programming language instead.